# No output from python script

Tags: python, sockets, http

I wanted to create a piece of code which takes in 2 lists (1st is an IP list, 2nd is a Port list). using iteration, I have tried to achieve connection (some addresses in the list are not working.) and getting the first HTTP page in order to check if the address is alive or dead.

This is the code I wrote:

```
import socket
import sys

ipees = []
portees = []

text_file = open("/home/loggyipport.txt", "r")
lines = text_file.readlines()

def go():
    for x in lines:
        ip, port = x.split()
        ipees.append(ip)
        portees.append(port)




go()

def dfunc(ipees, portees):
    for (ip, port) in zip(ipees, portees):
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.connect((ip, int(port)))
        s.send('GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n')
        while 1:
            buf = s.recv(1000)
        if not buf:
            break
        sys.stdout.write(buf)
        s.close()

dfunc(ipees, portees)
```

The script is running with no errors. 
The problem is that I get no output. 
Can someone figure out what is the problem?
Does my for loop using the 'zip' function is correctly written?

Comment: Why don't you use a proper HTTP access library, like [urllib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html) or at least [httplib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/httplib.html)?

Comment: Your program never reaches the line "sys.stdout.write(buf)" because it is stuck in the infinite while loop (it also never reaches the second ip address in your list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your dfunc function, the program successfully connects to the first IP and infinitely waits for data from the server because of that infinite loop. If all you want is to check that some data is received from the server, you do not need the while loop at all.

Here is a function that might do what you want:

```
def dfunc(ipees, portees):
    for (ip, port) in zip(ipees, portees):
        try:
            s = socket.create_connection((ip, port), timeout=10)
            s.send('GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n')
            buf = s.recv(1000)
            print buf
        except socket.error:
            print 'Could not connect to ({0}, {1})'.format(ip, port)
```

Comment: Hey, This exactly what ive needed. Thanks@!

Answer (score 1):

You don't return anything inside your functions, and you don't print anything to the console. The only time you do this is in `dfunc(ipees, portees)` where you have `sys.stdout.write(buf)`. Try adding a `sys.stdout.flush` to flush the buffer and print to the screen.

```
sys.stdout.write(buf)
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Actually, there's one more issue I may have found. Does the script ever terminate? You have an infinite `while` loop in `dfunc`.

```
while 1:
    buf = s.recv(1000)
```

I don't know much about `socket.socket` but it looks as if that loop will never terminate.

Your

```
 if not buf:
     break
```

is not part of your loop. You have to fix the indentation on that, so it becomes part of your loop. Thanks to [popovitsj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2947592/popovitsj) for pointing it out!

Comment: Looks like ` if not buf` misses an indentation

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the answer. I have added the sys.stdout.flush, yet no prompt. About the endless loop, I wish it to loop over the lists and try to connect, if it cant, it should just continue to the next items in the list. Any ideas..?

Comment: You can use the `continue` keyword. If executed, it will basically restart the loop on the next object.